# MySQL query correlating dayofweek and hour of sent messages

Tags: mysql, datetime, d3.js, dayofweek, hour

I have a database with a chat history that has a datime field, author of the messsage and the message.

I wan´t to make a query that returns a table that, correlates the weekday with hours of day, counting how many messages was sent.

Something like this:

```
+-------+--------+--------+----------+------------+---------+--------+---------+
| HOURS | SUNDAY | MONDAY | THURSDAY | WEDNESDAY  | TUESDAY | FRIDAY | SABBATH |
+-------+--------+--------+----------+------------+---------+--------+---------+
|  00   |   5    |   25   |   44     |     46     |   23    |   12   |   42    |
|  01   |   4    |   545  |   35     |     76     |   65    |   15   |   354   |
|  02   |   36   |   654  |   365    |     76     |   65    |   42   |   44    |
|  03   |   3    |   578  |   678    |     83     |   21    |   32   |   88    |
|  04   |   8    |   78   |   678    |     92     |   878   |   34   |   98    |
|  05   |   87   |   987  |   89     |     26     |   09    |   67   |   75    |
|  06   |   54   |   65   |   98     |     23     |   65    |   54   |   55    |
|  07   |   98   |   64   |   07     |     43     |   656   |   42   |   47    |
|  08   |   98   |   56   |   89     |     65     |   76    |   43   |   62    |
|  09   |   98   |   768  |   678    |     75     |   76    |   26   |   763   |
|  10   |   3    |   56   |   54     |     87     |   87    |   76   |   45    |
|  11   |   39   |   567  |   236    |     76     |   897   |   12   |   62    |
|  12   |   987  |   765  |   342    |     87     |   987   |   76   |   67    |
|  13   |   45   |   456  |   456    |     97     |   43    |   69   |   876   |
|  14   |   235  |   87   |   44     |     24     |   2865  |   98   |   86    |
|  15   |   543  |   987  |   44     |     45     |   367   |   87   |   87    |
|  16   |   897  |   87   |   64     |     37     |   898   |   67   |   98    |
|  17   |   678  |   67   |   76     |     54     |   245   |   56   |   87    |
|  18   |   766  |   89   |   99     |     54     |   689   |   35   |   24    |
|  19   |   98   |   98   |   987    |     55     |   467   |   76   |   25    |
|  20   |   45   |   73   |   789    |     62     |   98    |   35   |   177   |
|  21   |   876  |   897  |   35     |     289    |   56    |   76   |   57    |
|  22   |   876  |   978  |   546    |     35     |   874   |   24   |   543   |
|  23   |   76   |   945  |   456    |     64     |   87    |   64   |   76    |
+-------+--------+--------+----------+------------+---------+--------+---------+
```

It is possible to make that?

I have tried with this code, I think is a start, but I realy don´t know if I'm going in the right direction.

```
select
hour(sendtime) as 'HOUR',
dayofweek(sendtime) = 1 as 'Sunday',
dayofweek(sendtime) = 2 as 'Monday',
dayofweek(sendtime) = 3 as 'Tuesday',
dayofweek(sendtime) = 4 as 'Wednesday',
dayofweek(sendtime) = 5 as 'Thursday',
dayofweek(sendtime) = 6 as 'Friday',
dayofweek(sendtime) = 7 as 'Sabbath',
count(*) AS 'COUNT'
from chat
group by HOUR(sendtime)
```

I want this data to make a visualization usiging D3.js, something that looks like this:

http://www.imagesup.net/?di=16141790283414

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, you just need aggregation functions:

```
select hour(sendtime) as `HOUR`,
       sum(dayofweek(sendtime) = 1) as Sunday,
       sum(dayofweek(sendtime) = 2) as Monday,
       sum(dayofweek(sendtime) = 3) as Tuesday,
       sum(dayofweek(sendtime) = 4) as Wednesday,
       sum(dayofweek(sendtime) = 5) as Thursday,
       sum(dayofweek(sendtime) = 6) as Friday,
       sum(dayofweek(sendtime) = 7) as Sabbath,
       count(*) AS 'COUNT'
from chat
group by HOUR(sendtime)
order by `hour`;
```

Note that you do not need single quotes around column aliases.  You should only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought in using the sum() function but I didn't know how.